# Mysql Stored Procedure: match the column rule to retrieve value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, where-clause, operator-keyword

I have a stored procedure which function to retrieve the `ColumnProperty` based on the input parameter matching the `ColumnRule`.

For example,

I will execute the below to get the `ColumnProperty` as string(short). But the problem is when using WHERE to filter `ColumnRule`, the retrieved value is string and get unknown type at the end.

```
CALL `testing-spGetColumnType`('varchar(11)', @outputProperty);
select @outputProperty;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `testing-spGetColumnType`(IN pColumnType varchar(50),OUT pColumnProperty varchar(50))
BEGIN

    SELECT ColumnProperty FROM model_column_type where pColumnType like replace(ColumnRule, 'variable', pColumnType) into pColumnProperty;
    
    SELECT IFNULL(pColumnProperty,'unknown type') into pColumnProperty;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The sample table:

[image]

Comment: It won't execute the code in `ColumnRule` as a SQL expression. It's just a string and it's being matched against `pColumnType`.

Comment: echoing Barmar: the value from `ColumnRule` column is a *value*. It doesn't matter one whit that the string value looks like a SQL expression. As its referenced in the SELECT statement, it's just a collection of characters.  To get a value interpreted as SQL text (and open a potentially huge SQL Injection vulnerability) we would need dynamically generated SQL.. We could incorporate the value nto a string, and then execute the string as a SQL statement, PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE ... MySQL   
 Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

when the condition in the WHERE clause is evaluated against the `stringShort` row, given `'varchar(11)'` as the argument, it's equivalent to

```
  WHERE 'varchar(11)' 
   LIKE '%varchar% and SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(varchar(11),''('',-1),'')'',1) < 50'
```

and the result of the `LIKE` comparison will be FALSE.

The *value* of `ColumnRule` from that row

```
%varchar% and SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(variable,'(',-1),')',1) < 50
```

is a *value*. It doesn't matter that it looks like SQL text. In the context of the SELECT statement, it is just a string of characters. It's a string *value*. It is not references to identifiers, or SQL functions, or boolean operators.

We would get the same result if the `ColumnRule` value was

```
%varchar% one two buckle my shoe
```

---

To get a string value to be seen as SQL text, we can use dynamically prepared SQL.

In the context of MySQL PROCEDURE, we can dynamically create SQL text and store it as a string, and then execute the string, something like this:

```
 SET @foo = ' foo, bar' ; 
 SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ',@foo,' FROM mytab',' ORDER BY ',@foo); 
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

A word of caution: if we dynamically create SQL text, and incorporate potentially unsafe values, we can open a gaping SQL Injection vulnerability, ala Little Bobby Tables https://xkcd.com/327/

MySQL Reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html